# formtarget="_blank" not working in my submit button also in input type submit after submit

Tags: html, css

`formtarget="_blank"` is not working in my submit button or in input type submit after submiting the form it is not displaying on the new tab. Tested in chrome and Firefox browser.

```
<button type="submit" formtarget="_blank" class="btn green" 
value="Save &amp; Print"   name="spSlip" 
id="spSlip">Save &amp; Print</button>
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/sijizakuse/1/edit?html,js,output — I can't reproduce the problem when I test it.

Answer (score -2):

You could add an action to your form:

```
<form action="/newpage">
<input type="text">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Other then that, the **formtarget="_blank"** should work for the button as mentioned before.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i have multiple submit button and open only perticular one button in new tab not all

Comment: This was not clear at first. if formtaget="_blank" doesn't help then you can try with a bit of JavaScript:
------
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open Google in New Window</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.open("https://www.google.com");
}
</script>
------