# formtarget ="_blank" not working for button in chrome

Tags: html, chromium, opencart2.x

I am working on an opencart website, it has a button
which should open an invoice in a new tab.
When the button is clicked it opens the invoice is new tab as well as the current tab in the chrome.
this happens on the page where all the orders are listed, once the admin clicks on the checkbox next to the order and clicks the print invoice button the issue occurs.

it should only open the invoice in the new tab and not the same one as well.

I checked the issue on firefox and it's working properly.
i am using opencart  2.3.0.2

here's the code for the button

```
  <button type="submit" id="button-invoice" form="form-order"
          formaction="admin/index.php?route=sale/order/invoice&amp;token=dummytoken" 
          formtarget="_blank" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" 
          class="btn btn-info" data-original-title="Print Invoice"> 
          <i class="fa fa-print"></i> 
  </button>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146162/formtarget-blank-not-working-in-my-submit-button-also-in-input-type-submit-af

Comment: Have you considered using a normal link and styling it like a button?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing the `formtarget=“_blank”` ?

More info at
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6140064063029248

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below that work without any browser restriction.

```html
<form id="form" action="your-action.php" method="post" target="_blank">
     <button type="submit" form="form">Submit</button>
</form>
```